# How does the paramConverter actually work in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am having some confusion in understanding converters in symfony application.

This the docs

http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter

Now my main question is suppose i have this code where i have created many annotation which are extended `ParamConverter`

```
 * @Myannotation1("className")
 * @Myannotation2("view", options={"a1", "a2"})
 */
function getuserAction($className, array $view){
```

I have the `apply` function as written in docs

Now i want to know that

1. When i get `classname` from url then my annotation catches that, do something to it in `apply function` and then return it ,

Suppose `classname  =  User` before

Then my converter chnages that to

`classname  =  DataUser`

Now that new class Name will be passed as argument to function.

> Am i correct?

so from my undestanding what ever i return in apply function will be passed to the function as argument

am i correct?